# Python is showing a memory adress instead of printing

Tags: python, function, object

I'm trying just to print to see if the code is working.
But every time I print it show something like this "<**main**.pessoa object at 0x7f505f1c8710>"

I haven't find anything like this in my whole life.

```
class pessoa:

 def __init__(self,Nome="",Idade=0,CPF=0,Nacionalidade=""):
self._Nome = Nome
self._Idade = Idade
self._CPF = CPF
self._Nacionalidade = Nacionalidade

@property
def Nome(self):
return self._Nome

@Nome.setter
def Nome(self,Nome):
self._Nome = Nome

@property
def Idade(self):
return self._Idade

@Idade.setter
def Idade(self,Idade):
self._Idade = Idade

@property
def CPF(self):
return self._CPF

@CPF.setter
def CPF(self,CPF):
self._CPF = CPF

@property
def Nacionalidade(self):
return self._Nacionalidade

@Nacionalidade.setter
def Nacionalidade(self,Nacionalidade):
self._Nacionalidade = Nacionalidade

def comer(self):
print("Estou comendo")

p = pessoa (input ("Nome:"),input ("idade:"),input("CPF:"),input("Nacinalidade:"))
print(p)
```

Comment: `print()` displays the output of the `__str__()` method of the printed object. The default displays what you are observing.

Comment: What were you expecting it to print instead? That *is* what printing your objects looks like.

Comment: I modfied class pessoa to show the __str__() method below

Comment: As an aside, all your properties are completely pointless. Just use normal attributes, your getters and setters do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

override the **str**(self) function.
The following is an example:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "Nome=" + str(self._Nome) + ", Idade=" + str(self._Idade) + "..."
```

Comment: `def __str__(self):`, and try to use some string formatting instead of `+` and `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class pessoa:

 def __init__(self,Nome="",Idade=0,CPF=0,Nacionalidade=""):
  self._Nome = Nome
  self._Idade = Idade
  self._CPF = CPF
  self._Nacionalidade = Nacionalidade

 def __str__(self):
    return "\n"+ "Nome: " + self._Nome + "\n" + "Idada: " + self._Idade + "\n" + "CPF: " + self._CPF + "\n" + "Nacionalidade: " + self._Nacionalidade + "\n"

@property
def Nome(self):
  return self._Nome

@Nome.setter
def Nome(self,Nome):
  self._Nome = Nome

@property
def Idade(self):
  return self._Idade

@Idade.setter
def Idade(self,Idade):
  self._Idade = Idade

@property
def CPF(self):
  return self._CPF

@CPF.setter
def CPF(self,CPF):
  self._CPF = CPF

@property
def Nacionalidade(self):
  return self._Nacionalidade

@Nacionalidade.setter
def Nacionalidade(self,Nacionalidade):
  self._Nacionalidade = Nacionalidade

def comer(self):
  print("Estou comendo")

p = pessoa (input ("Nome:"),input ("idade:"),input("CPF:"),input("Nacinalidade:"))
print(p)
```

```
output:
Nome: Me
Idada: Me
CPF: Me
Nacionalidade: Metoo
```